# Type "Any" has no subscript members in Swift 3 during pulling array of data from server

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to update my project to swift 3.0 and all codes about pulling data from server is give me this error in the following picture.

[image]

I tried a lot of solutions that is available here but with no useful result what is the problem in this case ?

```
 do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)


        if let countries = json["Countries"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for country in countries {
                if let couname = country["countryname"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    country_names.append(couname)
                }

                if let coucode = country["code"] as? [AnyObject] {
                    country_codes.append(coucode)
                }

            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error Serializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting `json` to `[String: Any]` before using it.

Also you seem to have an error here: `if let couname = country["countryname"] as? [AnyObject]`

You should cast it to an array of `[String: AnyObject]`: `[[String: AnyObject]]`

The adjusted code would look like:

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

    if let countries = json["Countries"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for country in countries {
            if let couname = country["countryname"] as? [AnyObject] {
                country_names.append(couname)
            }

            if let coucode = country["code"] as? [AnyObject] {
                country_codes.append(coucode)
            }

        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Error Serializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of just a `let json`.

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }
```

Comment: I tried this line but now the error appears in the following lines at the two if statements 
 Type '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' has no subscript members